# How to dismiss keyboard in scrollview?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, keyboard, dismiss

The following code to dismiss the keyboard upon touching outside of it was working fine until I interspersed a scrollview between the uiview and the elements in storyboard to permit scrolling.  Now it is not working.  Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong?

```
//dismiss keyboard
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan:withEvent:");
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: does this view get any touches? what's your view hierarchy?

Comment: it used to.  Now there is a scrollview in between view and elements.  Hierarchy goes VC - view - scrollview-textfield, label etc.  Maybe I should change self.view to self.scrollView?  No that didn't fix problem.

Comment: Try :  scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;